# How to place image behind another image that has a transparent background

Tags: html, css

I have a rounded square box image that has a red strip that runs along the left side and has a transparent background (the white bit) which I created in photoshop. I would like to place an image behind this box. I have tried setting the `position:absolute` and `z-index: -1;` however, it places the image behind everything. Is there a way I can achieve this with just the CSS? P.S. I have searched for solutions but the ones I have come across did not seem to help me at all.

[image]

CSS:

```
#boxes img {
            border:1px solid;
            margin:4px 0 0 0px;
            padding:0;
            position: absolute;
            width: 359px;
            height: 218px;
            z-index: -1 ;
           -moz-border-radius-topright:5px;
           -moz-border-radius-topleft:5px;
           -moz-border-radius-bottomright:5px;
           -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:5px;
           -webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;
           -webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;
           -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
           -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;

 }

#boxes .box {
           width:370px;
           height:241px;
           float:left;
           background-image:url(../imgs/box_front.png);
           background-repeat:no-repeat;
           background-color:#FFF;
           margin:80px 30px 0 0;

}
```

Comment: Put z-index on all of your elements and give every element the proper index. More bigger the index, the element will appear more on top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reliably set `z-index` without setting `position` on your elements; the stacking is also relative to the elements' containers, so if everything is at root level the image with a negative `z-index` will disappear behind the page. (Personally, I try and avoid negative `z-index` values whenever possible.)

```
#boxes {
    position: relative;
}

#boxes img {
    border:1px solid;
    margin:4px 0 0 0px;
    padding:0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 359px;
    height: 218px;
    z-index: 1 ;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
 }

#boxes .box {
    width:370px;
    height:241px;
    float:left;
    background-image:url(../imgs/box_front.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color:#FFF;
    margin:80px 30px 0 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

## EDIT:

The problem is that your HTML is structured so the red stripe is the background image of the container that you're loading the image into. As this also has a `background-color`, the image is being lost behind it.

A better way of doing this would be to use HTML/CSS' natural document flow - i.e. the later the element appears in the HTML, the 'higher' it is in the natural z-index. This'll mean you don't have to specify `z-index` values, but you will need to add a presentational `div` to your code (unless you want to monkey around with `:after` pseudo-elements):

Each grey box will need to look like this:

```
<div class="grey box">
    <h3><a href="#">Stationary</a></h3>
    <a href="#" class="normal"><span class="border">&nbsp;</span><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/361/220"><div class="innerBox">&nbsp;</div></a>
</div>
```

... and your CSS will need to change. Remove the background from the `.box` styles, and add this to your CSS:

```
#boxes .innerBox {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;    
    width:370px;
    height:241px;
    background-image:url(http://i754.photobucket.com/albums/xx182/rache_R/box_front_zps196242cf.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

You can then remove the z-index from `#boxes .box`, and because the `innerBox` div appears after the image in your markup, it will naturally appear higher than your image.

If you can't add any extra HTML to your markup template, you could repurpose the `border` divs, which don't seem to be doing much:

```
#boxes .border
{
    border:none;
    z-index:1;
    cursor:pointer;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;    
    width:370px;
    height:241px;
    background-image:url(http://i754.photobucket.com/albums/xx182/rache_R/box_front_zps196242cf.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

You'll need to update your images too:

```
#boxes img {
    /* other declarations */
    position: absolute; 
    left: 4px; 
    top: 0;
    /* other declarations */
}
```

... and make sure your `#boxes .box` style has `position: relative;` set.

That should do you: http://jsfiddle.net/mr3Fq/4/

Comment: This works for me however, i have three boxes on one page and for some reason it has just put all three boxes on top of each other

Comment: all three boxes are no longer stacked on top of each other however, the image is now on top of the red box instead of behind it :S

Comment: Does the red box have a class of `.box`, or is that something else? It would help if we could see your HTML code too - or a jsFiddle would be even better.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. You're setting the red stripe as a background for the container that the image is sitting in. I'll update my answer with code to fix this, but you'll need to edit your HTML.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39725/discussion-between-ineed-ananswer-and-massivepenguin)